# sidewaysfigure: how to suppress rotation in pdf output

Tags: floats, pdf, rotating, printing

I am using `sidewaysfigure` from the `rotating` package.
The orientation of the figure is as desired for the double-page layout.
In the `pdf` (generated through Latex->PS->PDF), the page is rotated so that when viewing the file, the reader can see the figure in its correct orientation.

However, when I want to print the document the page is not rotated when using duplex printing. Instead, I get a shrunken page which is rotated by 90 degrees.

**EDIT**
Here is a minimal working example that illustrates my problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz} % this is just included to generate a "figure"

\begin{document}

This is just a test to show a rotated second page which won't print right in duplex mode.

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick,dashed,rounded corners] (12.25,1.5) rectangle (15.58,4.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{This is my sideways figure}
\end{center}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

The second page will be rotated counterclockwise (as expected), but will also be printed in this orientation:

[image: rotated second page]

**EDIT 2: Question**

How do I suppress the rotation of the page (not of the figure though) in the pdf-document that is created by Latex?
That way, I would not have to worry about any printer settings.

Comment: Could you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that exhibits the issue? This would give us something to start working with.

Comment: Thanks! I just compiled your MWE and printed it twice (once to paper and once to a PDF); it worked as expected in both cases (page number in normal position; figure rotated so the caption is on the _outside_ (left) edge). So it must be some local setting/issue. Unless anyone else has ideas?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a printer-related issue.

Comment: I do not think, it is off-topic, because a page can be rotated in different ways: the physical page format is rotated or the physical page is kept, but the rotation is indicated in the PDF object by the `/Rotate` key. How both ways can be done in LaTeX is on-topic.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I rephrased the question to make it more Latex specific.

Comment: Schorsch: Sorry, I acted based on your previous comment. @HeikoOberdiek Ok, I voted to reopen.

Comment: If using Acrobat, you need to select `Auto` instead of `Portrait` in the print options. Also just put `\centering` instead of `center` environment.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered a problem like this before, and for me it was something that happened in the pdf conversion: my own .ps files looked fine. It was solved by running ps2pdf as follows:

`ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None filename.ps`

(where filename.ps is replaced with your postscript file)

I tried this with your MWE, and I went from the pdf displaying the rotated page, to all pages oriented in portrait mode.

Comment: Upvote as this works. I am still curious if there is a fix from within the `sidewaysfigure`